# Counting the basic operations of a given program

Tags: c++, performance, runtime, big-o

I am looking at the following: [Operations Counting Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKWMjrtkjUwa3NCaTh6M2FWemM/view?usp=sharing)

Which is supposed to present the operations count of the following pseudocode:

```
Algorithm prefixAverages(A)
 Input array A of n numbers
 Output array B of n numbers such that B[i] is the average
 of elements A[0], A[1], … , A[i]

for i = 0 to n - 1 do
   b = 0
   for j = 0 to i do
       b = b + A[j]
       j++;
   B[i] = b / (i + 1)
return B
```

But I don't see how the counts on the inner for loop are reached. It says that for case `i=0; j=0;` the inner for loop runs twice? But it strikes me that it should only run once to see that `0 < 0`. Can anyone provide insight into where the given operations count comes from or provide their own operations count?

This is under the assumption that primitive operations are:

- Assignment
- Array access
- Mathematical operators (+, -, /, *)
- Comparison
- Increment/Decrement (math in disguise)
- Return statements

Let me know if anything is unclear or you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the article you are following says "for var <- 0 to var2", it is like "for (var = 0; var <= var2; var++), so yes, when i = 0, it enters the "for" twice (once when i = 0, and again when i = 1, then it goes out).
(Sorry if bad english)

Edit and improve: When I calculate the complexity of a program, the only thing that interest me is the big O complexity; in this case, you have that the 'i' loop run 'n' times, and the 'j' loop run 'i' times, so the 'i' loop runs (1+2+3+...+n) times, that is n(n+1)/2 times, and that is an O(n**2) complexity.

In the first line, you have an assignament (i = something), and a comparison (i <= n-1) ("2 operations") for each i value, and as the last value is i=n, it does those 2 operations since i=0, until i=n, and as those are n+1 values (from 0 to n), this line do 2(n+1) operations.

The second line is a little obvious, as it enters the loop n times (since i=0, until i=n-1).

On the second loop, it do 2 things, an assignament, and a comparison (just as the first loop), and it do this i+2 times (for example, when i=0, it enters the loop 1 time, but it has to do the i=1 assignament, and the 1<=0 comparison, so its 2 times in total), so it do this calculus 2(i+2) times, but it do this since i=0, until i=n-1, so to calculate all of this, we have to do the sum (sum from i=0 until i=n-1: 2(i+2)) = 2((sum of i from 0 to n-1) + (sum of 2 from i=0 to i=n-1)) = 2((n(n-1)/2) + 2n) = n(n-1) + 4n = n"2 - n + 4n = n"2 + 3n.

I'll continue this later, I hope my answer so far is helpful for you. (again, sorry if some bad english)